# How can I make a DNS mapping using NGINX

Tags: nginx, dns, digital-ocean

I'm really new to NGINX.

Currently, I have a containerized app (PHP Application) in my server; and it is can be viewed via 192.168.1.20:8080 (ip address is just an example). The app is perfectly fine.

But, I want my app to be able to viewed via 'my-domain-name.com/my-app'. Can I achieve this? I've searched for the solutions and a lot of them are using subdomains instead.

I've also tried below configurations under /etc/nginx/sites-available/my-app. But none of them works.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name my-domain-name.com/my-app;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.20:8080;
    }
}
```

```
server {
root /var/www/html;
        listen 80; 
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name my-domain-name.com/my-app www.my-domain-name.com/my-app;
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://192.168.1.20:8080;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`server_name` property requires a domain name and does not support subdirectories.

You can specify your path in `location` property:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name my-domain-name.com;

    location /my-app {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.20:8080;
    }
}
```

(source: [nginx docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html))

Comment: @SatNaing Just tried it with my nginx routing to ASP.NET Core, it routes successfully, but I did have to rework the backend to handle URLs as `example.com/my-app/page` instead of `example.com/page`.